# .Net Panel, possible to zoom on panel's graphics?

Tags: .net, panel, system.drawing

If i have a panel where I am drawing generic shapes on its CreateGraphics() object, like below:

```
            public static void DrawRoundRectWithText(Graphics g, Pen p, float x, float y, float width, float height, float radius, string textFirstLike, string textSecondsLine, bool hasGate, Color color)
    {
        System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = g;
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;


        drawBrush.Color = color;
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, (int)width, (int)height);
        p.Width = RECTANGLE_BORDER;

        formGraphics.FillRectangle(drawBrush, rect);
        p.Color = RECTANGLE_COLOR;
        formGraphics.DrawRectangle(p, rect);


        DrawString(g, textFirstLike, x + TEXT_OFFSET_X, y + height / 4, PRIMARY_TEXT_FONT_SIZE, (int)width);
        DrawString(g, textSecondsLine, x + TEXT_OFFSET_X, y + height / 2, SECONDARY_TEXT_FONT_SIZE, (int)width);

        int gateWidth = QuestNode.GATE_RADIUS;
        int gateHeight = QuestNode.GATE_RADIUS;

        if (hasGate)
        {

            drawBrush.Color = GATE_COLOR;
            Rectangle circle = new Rectangle((int)(x + width) - gateWidth/2, (int)(y + height) - gateHeight/2, gateWidth, gateHeight);

            formGraphics.FillEllipse(drawBrush, circle);
            formGraphics.DrawEllipse(p, circle);

        }

        Point[] diamondPoints = new Point[4];
        diamondPoints[0] = new Point((int)(x - gateWidth / 2), (int)y);
        diamondPoints[1] = new Point((int)x, (int)(y - gateHeight / 2));
        diamondPoints[2] = new Point((int)(x + gateWidth / 2), (int)y);
        diamondPoints[3] = new Point((int)x, (int)(y + gateHeight / 2));

        drawBrush.Color = Color.LightGray;
        formGraphics.FillPolygon(drawBrush, diamondPoints);
        formGraphics.DrawPolygon(p, diamondPoints);
    }
```

[image]

Is there maybe a way where you could zoom in/out on the panel, therefore automatically shrinking the shapes?

Comment: You can use the **System.Drawing.Graphics.ScaleTransform()** method. Anyway let's check what you're doing: to rebuild resources (brushes and pens) each time is **terribly inefficient** (and you do not even explicitly deallocate them).

Comment: That works great. Thank you very much! I've updated the complete code that I am using for drawing those shapes, where the Graphics and the Pen objects are created upon initialisation and are the only ones used for all the shapes. Can that code be optimised do you think? Thanks again. P.S. Does the ScaleTranform affect the values returned by the MouseDown event when clicking on the panel?

Comment: No, MouseDown won't be affected (because the scale is applied to drawing only). You'll need to scale click location according to your zoom factor (and offset). You reassign the Color property of your brushes, it consumes less resources than creating new ones but it's not so optimal: just keep one brush/pen for each constant color (and   use a dictionary as cache for "variable" colors). Moreover you may try to use StringFormat when you draw your text (but I don't see your DrawString implementation so I just guess).